# Postgres upgrade from 10 to 12: pg_upgrade fail for presence of required library

Tags: database, postgresql, upgrade, postgresql-10, postgres-12

```
$ /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_upgrade \
> -b /usr/pgsql-1
pgsql-10/ pgsql-12/
> -b /usr/pgsql-10/bin/ \
> -B /usr/pgsql-12/bin/ \
> -d /var/lib/pgsql/1
10/ 12/
> -d /var/lib/pgsql/10/data/ \
> -D /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/ \
> --check

Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions ok
Checking database user is the install user ok
Checking database connection settings ok
Checking for prepared transactions ok
Checking for system-defined composite types in user tables ok
Checking for reg* data types in user tables ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch ok
Checking for tables WITH OIDS ok
Checking for invalid "sql_identifier" user columns ok
Checking for presence of required libraries fatal



Your installation references loadable libraries that are missing from the
new installation. You can add these libraries to the new installation,
or remove the functions using them from the old installation. A list of
problem libraries is in the file:
loadable_libraries.txt



Failure, exiting


[postgres@localhost ~]$ cat loadable_libraries.txt
could not load library "$libdir/ltree": ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/ltree": No such file or directory
Database: ___
Database: ___
could not load library "$libdir/pg_trgm": ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
Database: ___
Database: ___
could not load library "$libdir/uuid-ossp": ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory
Database: ___
Database: ___
```

Valid steps for upgrade from postgres 10 to 12 will be highly appreciated. As I didn't found any highly reviewed link that is complete.
I am currently following with this link: https://www.postgresql.r2schools.com/how-to-upgrade-from-postgresql-11-to-12/. Replaced `10` for `11` in every command.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well, what is in loadable_libraries.txt?

Answer (score 5):

You can run the command:

```
sudo dnf install postgresql12-contrib
```

Comment: Thanks, this also solved my errors: `could not load library "$libdir/pg_trgm": ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_trgm": No such file or directory
could not load library "$libdir/adminpack": ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/adminpack": No such file or directory
could not load library "$libdir/btree_gist": ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/btree_gist": No such file or directory`